# UI CHARTS ( for indices time series in python API of Google earth Engine)

Tags: python, google-maps-api, google-earth-engine

If I use python api for google earth engine and want to make a UI chart for mean value of NDVI for a particular year , how does the UI.CHART function work in python api for google earth engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a library in the universe of Jake Vanderplas that I have used to make charts in Google Earth Engine: `pygal`. May not be the best or newest, but it works. I have incorporated the method in a python package called [ipygee](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/ipygee). You can install it via `pip`.

At the moment, the only method available is `series` (to plot a time series), but I am about to incorporate `seriesByRegion`, because I need them for work, the rest will have to wait.

There is a notebook in which I show how to use it: [Chart.ipynb](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/ipygee/blob/master/examples/Chart.ipynb), and the equivalent code in JS (https://code.earthengine.google.com/e50afcbdc75fbb9611a4ac7d6567fdf8)

I leave the code here as well:

```
# coding: utf-8
# # chart module

import ee    
import ipygee as ui

test_site = ee.Geometry.Point([-71, -42])
    
# ## Time Series
years = ee.List([2015, 2016, 2017, 2018])
    
col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(test_site)

def make_time_series(year):
    ''' make a time series from years list '''
    eefilter = ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, field='year')
    filtered = col.filter(eefilter)
    return filtered.mean().set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).millis())

time_series = ee.ImageCollection(years.map(make_time_series))

# ## Chart *series*
chart_ts = ui.chart.Image.series(**{
    'imageCollection': time_series, 
    'region': test_site,
    'scale': 10,
    'bands': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']
})

# chart_ts.renderWidget()  # for Jupyter Notebook or Lab
chart_ts.render_in_browser()  # for Spyder
```

As the resulting chart `chart_ts` is a subclass of a `pygal` chart, you can use [all its methods](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/output.html), like `render_to_file`, etc, and all its attributes.

Comment: I already finished `seriesByRegion` =)

Comment: Would "from geetools import chart" now be "from ipygee import chart" ?

Comment: yes! thank you @svollowork

Answer (score 6):

The [ui.Chart class](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts) is only available in the [Earth Engine Code Editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground) application. It is not part of the JavaScript or Python API libraries.

Using the Earth Engine Python API, you can pull data into a Python data structure (such as a Pandas dataframe) and use a wide variety of Python visualization libraries to view the data. For a good overview of popular libraries, see Jake Vanderplas' talk [The Python Visualization Landscape](https://youtu.be/FytuB8nFHPQ) from PyCon 2017.

Comment: Thank you Tyler for the suggestion. I am presently working with real time analysis using Earth Engine and it would be great to stay in touch

Comment: when working with large data I think it is not a best practice to pull the data into the client-side. Is there any way to work on charts on the server-side using Python API?